# How do I neatly convert my data type for a "for" loop in python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, for-loop, types

I have a DataFrame (1284 rows, 22 columns)
I want to make a scatter plot of each column vs the first column so I will have 21 plots.
In the below "for" loop I use the columns of my DataFrame as counter. That works nicely. *col1* is a *str*-type.

In the "for" loop i use the col1 (count) to get the corresponding column from my DataFrame. This does not work. I suppose (I know pretty sure) it is due to the fact that I use a *str* in my *for* loop and DataFrame in my column selection.

Is there a neat way to solve this?

```
for col1 in DataImport.columns:
    x=DataImport.loc[:,"FUEL RATE"]
    y=DataImport.loc[:,col1]
    axs[col1].plot(x,y)
```

error

```
  File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\berndwagner\onedrive - locmaint\documenten\wdw rail\python\datamining.py:44
    axs[col1].plot(x,y)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I tried to prior to the *for* loop changing DataTypes but that got messy elsewhere in the code and I horsed around with adding `.index`. No success. Plus I wondered if there was a neat way to just add something to the `y = DataImport.loc..` line.

Comment: The error you're encountering is because you're trying to use a column name `(col1)` as an index to access the subplot `axs[col1]`. You can't use a string as an index like that; you need to use an integer. You can solve this issue by iterating over both the column names and their corresponding indices. You can also create a subplot for each column and then plot the data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

With saleh7's suggestion, I answered my own question. First I get my DataFrame size and then make a range out of that for my loop.. thanks

```
m=len(DataImport.columns)
for col1 in range(1,m+1):
    x=DataImport.loc[:,"FUEL RATE"]
    print(col1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).